# Game asset n-gons management doubts

Tags: modeling, game-engine, topology, knife-tool, polycount

i am a relative beginner. I have a question that i am not able to answer, i know that in general n-gons are fine on flat surfaces if the model doesn't have to be deformed and quads are not necessary all the times. The problem is: i had to make this asset, and for now i really like the boolean workflow because it's fast. After the boolean if the shading is ok use the triangulation modifier and as far as i know inside the game engine then everything should be fine. I also have to keep the polycount low.
The problem is that the guy who gave me the task asked to not leave n-gons, so i tried to convert it to quads with knife but it's really tedious and long so i hope to don't have to do this again honestly. The polycount is also much higher compared to the first model with n-gons, and since i have to keep the polycount low this makes no sense to me. My idea was to model with my boolean workflow and simply apply the triangolation in the end. In fact the model with n-gons and triangulation has exactly the same as the one with quads and the shading is perfect. What can i do to avoid using knife for 2 hours to make all quads? I really enjoy modelling but i just can't understand the sense of this part.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should ask if you're authorized to use triangles, as they are N-Gons but are supported by game engines. They just are awful for anything related to subdivision or animation. If you can use triangles, use the workflow leading to the right model, and in edit mode use "Triangulate" or a "Triangulate" modifier before exporting your model

Answer (score 0):

The effects of the modifier must not be shown in the final poly count unless it is applied. This makes some sense as a modifier is not permanent.

Since this model has a lot of faces that are parallel to each-other, I recommend you apply all modifiers and run a limited dissolve operation before running triangulate (also available as an operator).